# How to remote access a Raspberry Pi (maybe Apache Guacamole)?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, docker, remote, guacamole

I've recently taken up Python programming from a Raspberry Pi which is a lot of fun. The Pi is set up at home but I travel a lot and I would like to be able to access the Pi remotely so I can continue programming from where ever I'm at. I'd like to be able to log in from different OS as my laptop runs Linux and my work computer is Windows. Here are my questions:

1. What's the best software for remote accessing? I've looked into Apache Guacamole and like that it's clientless and opensource. Will Guacamole do what I want?
2. If Guacamole is suitable, should I set it up with Docker?
3. How do I minimize potential security risks?
4. Any good tutorials on how to set this up?

Please let me know if you would suggest a different set-up or software. Just looking for suggestions on how to gain remote access to my Raspberry Pi from any OS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full desktop with GUI, then **TeamViewer** is a good alternative. There is software for Windows, macOS, Linux and host software for Raspberry Pi. It's free for personal/non-commercial usage. It works really well. You don't have open up ports in firewalls etc.

If you only need shell access to run commands and transfer files, then **ssh** is all you need. That is already built into Raspberry OS. You will need to forward a port in the firewall to connect from outside. Default is port 22, but you could also "hide" the ssh-service a little bit by using a different port in the higher range.

ssh is generally considered quite secure and you can use keys instead of password for logging in, which is good both for security and convenience when you connect. I almost only use my RPis without screen and over ssh anyway.

Think about security. Is it secure enough for the type of information you store on the RPi?
Regardless of what you store on the RPi itself, you may want to isolate the RPi from the rest of your home network. In case somebody does get access to it, they can't use it to get to other devices on the same network.

There are plenty of other software alternatives, but if you are a beginner I think these two options are a good place to start.